# identifying a superset of tags under a node in an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform an XML such that all nodes of a particular name contain a superset of all the elements that are available under those nodes.

For example, Here is the input xml. In this xml, the group could contain one or more item nodes. The caller will only pass only the items that are available under that group.

```
<group>
   <item>
       <name> item1 </name>
       <value> 10 </value>
   </item>
</group>
<group>
    <item>
       <name> item2 </name>
       <value> 20 </value>
     </item>
</group>
```

The requirement is to transform it to the one shown below, where the item nodes from all the group should be part of each group. However, if that item is not available in the input under that group, it should be filled with a value of 0.

```
<group>
   <item>
       <name> item1 </name>
       <value> 10 </value>
   </item>
   <item>
       <name> item2 </name>
       <value> 0 </value>
   </item>
</group>
<group>
     <item>
       <name> item1 </name>
       <value> 0 </value>
     </item>    
    <item>
       <name> item2 </name>
       <value> 20 </value>
     </item>
</group>
```

Could you please let me know how this can be achieved using XSLT ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to add, the content of <name> under <item> is not among a per-defined set and can have any user given value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. +1 for a good first question (although an example of what you've already tried would've been nice).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it (in XSLT 2.0 since you didn't specify)...

**XML Input** (wrapped in `<groups>` to be well-formed)

```
<groups>
    <group>
        <item>
            <name> item1 </name>
            <value> 10 </value>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group>
        <item>
            <name> item2 </name>
            <value> 20 </value>
        </item>
    </group>
</groups>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="names" select="distinct-values(/*/group/item/name)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="group">
        <xsl:variable name="currentItems" select="item/name"/>
        <xsl:variable name="items" as="node()*">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$names[not(. = current()/item/name)]">
                <item>
                    <name><xsl:value-of select="."/></name>
                    <value> 0 </value>
                </item>
            </xsl:for-each>         
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:perform-sort select="$items">
                <xsl:sort select="name"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<groups>
   <group>
      <item>
         <name> item1 </name>
         <value> 10 </value>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name> item2 </name>
         <value> 0 </value>
      </item>
   </group>
   <group>
      <item>
         <name> item1 </name>
         <value> 0 </value>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name> item2 </name>
         <value> 20 </value>
      </item>
   </group>
</groups>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This both an XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vGroupContent" select="/*/group/node()"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="group">
  <group>
   <xsl:apply-templates select=
    "node()|@*|$vGroupContent[not(name = current()/item/name)]">
    <xsl:with-param name="pGroup" select="."/>
     <xsl:sort select="name"/>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
  </group>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:param name="pGroup"/>
  <item>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
    <value> <xsl:value-of select=
    "value/text()[generate-id($pGroup) = generate-id(../../..)]"/>

    <xsl:if test=
     "value/text()[not(generate-id($pGroup) = generate-id(../../..))]"> 0 </xsl:if>
    </value>
  </item>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
    <group>
        <item>
            <name> item1 </name>
            <value> 10 </value>
        </item>
    </group>
    <group>
        <item>
            <name> item2 </name>
            <value> 20 </value>
        </item>
    </group>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <group>
      <item>
         <name> item1 </name>
         <value> 10 </value>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name> item2 </name>
         <value> 0 </value>
      </item>
   </group>
   <group>
      <item>
         <name> item1 </name>
         <value> 0 </value>
      </item>
      <item>
         <name> item2 </name>
         <value> 20 </value>
      </item>
   </group>
</t>
```

Comment: I believe you missed the "`However, if that item is not available in the input under that group, it should be filled with a value of 0."` part of the question.